# Combine results from 3 sql queries to calculate running stock

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to calculate the stock by product a warehouse had over time. I have the information about today's stock, and also the amount of products sold and purchased by day. So, the calculation for yesterday values would be: 
Yesterday_stock=Stock-yesterday_sold_quantity+yesterday_purchased_quantity. My problem is that i should save somewhere the amount of everyday's stock in order to calculate the stock of the previous day. I found that in order to do that i could use over sql clause with order by. But unfortunately, i have sql server 2008 and this is not a choice.

The tables are:
Prdamount which holds the current stock per product (StuPrdID ) and if it is blocked for some reason.

```
|-------------- |------------------|---------------
|      StuPrdID |    StuQAmount    |prdBlockingReason
|---------------|------------------|-------------
|          12345|         16       | 
|---------------|------------------|--------------
|          08889|         12       |   expired
|---------------|------------------|------------
```

Table Moves which holds information about inserts and outputs of products. If MoveCase field has value equal 1 it is an output move, if it is a 2 it is a purchased quantity. Moves table dummy data:

```
    |-------------- |--------------------- -|--------|-------
    |MoveItemCode   |    MoveDate           |MoveCase|MoveRealQty
    |---------------|---------------------- |--------|-------
    |     12345     |2018-06-24 00:00:00.000|  1     |14
    |---------------|-----------------------|--------|--------
    |     08889     |2018-06-24 00:00:00.000|  2     |578
    |---------------|-----------------------|--------|--------
```

and table Product with information related with data:

```
|-------------- |------------------|
|      PrdCode  |   PrdDespription |
|---------------|------------------|
|          12345|      Orange juice| 
|---------------|------------------|
|          08889|         Chocolate|   
|---------------|------------------|
```

I want an output like this:

```
  |------------|--------------------- -|--------|--------------|------------
  |Prdcode     | PrdDescription        |Stock   |Stock 18/07/03|Stock 18/7/02
  |------------|---------------------- |--------|--------------|------------
  |     12345  |Orange Juice           |  80    |50              34
  |----------- |-----------------------|--------|--------------|------------
  |     08889  |Chocolate              |  45    |82              17
  |------------|-----------------------|--------|--------------|-------------
```

this query gives me the running stock:

```
select 
product.PrdCode,
product.PrdDescr,
SUM(StuQAmount) as Stock
from prdamount
left join product on (product.PrdID=prdamount.StuPrdID)
where prdamount.prdBlockingReason=' '
group by product.PrdCode,product.PrdDescr
order by product.PrdCode asc
```

This query gives me the quantity sold by product per day:

```
select 
moves.MoveItemCode,
prd.PrdDescr,
moves.MoveDate,
SUM(MoveRealQty) as 'sold_quantity'
from moves
left join prd on (moves.MoveItemCode=product.PrdCode)
where (moves.MoveDate>'2018-06-01' and  and moves.MoveCase=1)
group by moves.MoveItemCode,product.PrdDescr,moves.MoveDate
order by moves.MoveItemCode asc,moves.MoveDate asc
```

And this query gives me the quantity purchases by product per day:

```
select 
moves.MoveItemCode,
prd.PrdDescr,
moves.MoveDate,
SUM(MoveRealQty) as 'Purchased_Quantity'
from Moves
left join product on (moves.MoveItemCode=product.PrdCode)
where  (moves.MoveDate>'2018-06-01' and moves.MoveCase=2)
group by moves.MoveItemCode,product.PrdDescr,moves.MoveDate
order by moves.MoveItemCode asc,moves.MoveDate asc
```

I tried to combine these 3 queries into one using subqueries, but it didn't work. So how can i accomplish the result that i want? Sorry if the question is silly, i am a beginner in sql

Comment: Could you please add your data structure and some dummy data with a desired output?  It will make it much easier for us to help

Comment: Ok dave i think that it's better now

Comment: And what is your desired output from that data?

Comment: It it ok now? I made an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
select 
product.PrdCode,
moves.MoveItemCode,
product.PrdDescr,
moves.MoveDate,
SUM( case when moves.MoveCase=1 then MoveRealQty else 0 end) as 'sold_quantity',
SUM( case when moves.MoveCase=2 then MoveRealQty else 0 end) as 'Purchased_Quantity',
(select SUM(StuQAmount) from prdamount where StuPrdID = product.PrdID and prdBlockingReason=' ')
from moves
left join product on (moves.MoveItemCode=product.PrdCode)
where (moves.MoveDate>'2018-06-01')
group by moves.MoveItemCode,product.PrdDescr,moves.MoveDate, product.PrdCode
order by moves.MoveItemCode asc,moves.MoveDate asc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Satya. I wasn't clear in what i wanted to do. Your code is fine but i cannot calculate the stock the warehouse had before two weeks for example. I made a edit in order to help